# failed to read inch symbol in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have csv with below details

```
Name,Desc,Year,Location

Jhon,12" Main Third ,2012,GR

Lew,"291" Line (12,596,3)",2012,GR

,All, 1992,FR
```

...

It is very long file. i just showed problematic lines.I am confused how can i read it in Pandas data frame, I tried

- quotechar,
- quoting,
- sep

  like attribute of pandas **read_csv**.
  Still no success.

I have no control on how csv is being designed.

Comment: Are your lines like this one : `Jhon,12" Main Third ,2012,GR` ? Why is there odd number of quotes?

Comment: `12"`= 12 inches (= 1 foot, = 30.48 cm). The US should just stop using IP units altogether, and you wouldn't have this problem! :)

Comment: I alreayd said, I can not change CSV.I made no typo in my question.Please try to find me solution

Comment: I was just answering MMF's question.

The main problem I have with your csv file is this `"291" Line (12,596,3)"`. That's just terrible design.

Comment: MMF: that one is inch symbol

Comment: Julien ; My bad luck I got CSV like this, still need to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Try if this works for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

l1=[]
with open('/home/yusuf/Desktop/c1') as f:
    headers = f.readline().strip('\n').split(',')
    for a in f.readlines():
        if a:
            q = re.findall("^(\w*),(.*),\s?(\d+),(\w+)",a)
            if q:
                l1.append(q)

l2 = [list(b[0]) for b in l1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=l2, columns=headers)
df
```

Output:

[image]

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/AU2WcO/1

Comment: @Notepad Yes. You might have to fine tune the regex to consider other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the separator character inside a field.
For example, in

```
Lew,"291" Line (12,596,3)",2012,GR
```

Pandas will assume you have 6 fields because you have 5 commas, even if two of them are between quotes. You would need to do some pre-processing  of the text file to get rid of this issue, or ask for a different separator character (@ or | seem to work well in my experience.

Pandas has no problems reading the other lines:

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.read_csv('untitled.txt')

   Name             Desc  Year Location
0  Jhon  12" Main Third   2012       GR
1   NaN              All  1992       FR
```

Comment: it is all I have, csv is not made by me, already said, stiil need to find solution

Comment: @Notepad Yeah, you need to do some preprocessing first to remove the issue then.

Comment: that means I need to process that much larger file using python

Comment: @Notepad As far as I can tell, yes, you do. There are solutions for both parsing the rows with incomplete quotes and the rows with quoted commas (`pd.read_csv('untitled.txt', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`), but both break when trying to to the other case.

Comment: Robert: I digged all over internet, not found any solution, So I came here

Comment: @Notepad Yes. Again, as far as I know the solution is to preprocess and fix the data. Is because of these kind of things that data cleanup is such a big deal - badly formatted data is everywhere.