# Pandas read_csv with inch symbol between quotechar='"', semicolon delimited

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Thank you all for taking a look at this problem. I have searched for the past few hours and there doesn't seem to be a solution that handles this specific problem. I have a semicolon delimited file with double quote as the quotechar. I am trying to use Pandas read_csv, which normally works fine, but I received a file that contains an inch symbol " in a field (enclosed in double quotes)....which is causing the fields to be shifted.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';', quotechar='"', encoding='ISO-8859-1',converters={i: str for i in range(0, 155)})
```

Below is a sample of the data (header and data row).....the converter shows 155, which is the length, but for simplicity sake, I have only included what is pertinent.

```
"description";"charge_1";"charge_1";"charge_2";"address"
"CSM glove sample 10"";"";"";"345 island ln"
```

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: I don't know if it's possible for you (if you have control of that csv). Parsing csv files is a nightmare on a prod env. you're much better off switching to parquet. Take a look at pyArrow

Comment: Interesting problem. The cell escape is incorrect, it should be `"CSM glove sample 10"""`. The quote should be escaped with a qoute.

Comment: @CarlosPCeballos, unfortunately, I do not have control over the csv coming in.

Comment: @Phineas, there could be many cases in the future where the inch symbol is passed. This is from a major parcel carrier...so I have no ability to get them to change or predict what they may pass in the future.

Comment: If the data is not too long, you could search how many quotes each cell has and if it more than one you could replace all the middle quotes with something else. And then do read_csv

Comment: @tdelaney I agree with your comment about the escape quote. I am not a regexp expert, but I think to solve the problem you have to replace the following:

a non-quote character followed by two double quotes followed by a semicolon WITH the non-quote character followed by three double quotes followed by a semicolon.

Then use read_csv

But it would not handle situations where the inch symbol was passed in the middle of the string vs the end (which it is in this case)

Comment: @Stephen - That's a good idea - but it would have to be two d-quotes not preceded by a d-quote or backslash (maybe the upstream writer gets fixed and starts qouting correctly. The unknown is d-qoutes within the data, but not at the end. If they are not escaped at all (which appears likely) then they'll still be a problem. So a single d-qoute character not preceded by a d-quote or followed by a semicolon?

Comment: @Notepad You posted several years ago in this article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058534/failed-to-read-inch-symbol-in-pandas-read-csv) regarding the same issue, but I never saw a solution to the pre-processing. Did you find a solution? If so, would you please share. Thanks .... I do not have a reputation of greater than 50, so I cannot comment on your post.

Comment: i would recommend using ";" as a delimiter and removing " " between object